# How do I get rid of complexity in txt file?

Tags: java

I have Person class and its properties are:

```
public class Person {
    String Name;
    Gender gender;
    Person father;
    Person mother;
    Person partner;
    ArrayList<Person> childs = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public enum Gender {
        MAN, WOMAN
    }
    
    public Person(String name, Gender gender){
        this.Name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    
    public void marryTo(Person person){
        this.partner = person;
        person.partner = this;
    }
    
     public void setChildFromMarriage(Person child){
         childs.add(child);
         partner.childs.add(child);
     }
}
```

I am getting the properties of persons from a txt file. Each line represents one person. Properties in a line are separated by a slash.
Txt file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha3Wi.png

```
package classPackage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import classPackage.Person.Gender;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            MainClass obj = new MainClass ();
            obj.run ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
    
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public void run () {
        ArrayList<String> lines = null;
        try {
            lines = readFile("/persons.txt");
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        for(String line: lines) {
            Person p = loadPerson(line);
            persons.add(p);
        }
    }
    
    private Person loadPerson(String line) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int which_gender = 0;
        Gender gender = null;
        String name = null;
        int which_father = 0;
        int which_mother = 0;
        int which_partner = 0;
        int s = 0;
        String strS;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(j);
            if ((int) ch == 47) {
                strS = sb.toString();
                s++;
                sb.setLength(0);
                if (s == 1) {
                    which_gender = Integer.parseInt(strS);
                    if(which_gender == 0) {
                        gender = Gender.MAN;
                    } else if(which_gender == 0) {
                        gender = Gender.WOMAN;
                    }
                }
                else if(s == 2)
                    name = strS;
                else if(s == 3)
                    which_father = Integer.parseInt(strS);
                else if(s == 4)
                    which_mother = Integer.parseInt(strS);
                else if(s == 5)
                    which_partner = Integer.parseInt(strS);
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        
        Person person = new Person(name, gender);
        
        if(which_father != -1) {
            person.father = persons.get(which_father);  
        }
        if(which_mother != -1) {
            person.mother = persons.get(which_mother);
            persons.get(which_mother).setChildFromMarriage(person);
        }       
        if(which_partner != -1) {
            person.marryTo(persons.get(which_partner));
        }

        return person;
    }
    
    private ArrayList<String> readFile(String filename) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        File file = new File(getClass().getResource(filename).toURI());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                reader.close();
                break;
            }           
            lines.add(line);
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

I tried to summarize my problem with these lines of code.
My problem is:
I don't know if it is related to the primitiveness of the txt file but I have 2 problems.

1. e.g. I always need to initialize son objects after their father. Otherwise "persons.get(which_father);" It will return IndexOutOfBoundsException error.
2. For example, there are 10 people registered in my txt file. (0-9 index) Let the father of the person in 9.index be the person in index 3. When I delete the person in index 1 and delete and save the 1.index line from the txt file; now our man's father is in index 2, not index 3. Changing the number of the father from 3 to 2 is complicated.

I feel unnecessarily complicated to operate on the txt file. How can I solve these 2 problems and code complexity?

Comment: The issue you have is you are using the line number (essentially) as an "index" that creates relationships between the entities in the file - _But_, there is no programmatic representation of that index/relationship that is maintained between both environments (file vs. memory). You basically have to create a mini RDBMS in memory using a few data structures (Maps and Sets) to deal with this.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your last sentence. By a mini RDBMS do you mean creating something like: Creating a String ID for each object in the txt file and associating it with the people with using the hashmap on code. And I guess instead of saving all the properties of a person on a single line, first initializing all persons with properties such as name, age, and then creating parent-son, husband-wife relations with using id's in a different txt file

Comment: This is a classic case of some arbitrary data structure driving how you create a solution that is completely unrelated to that file. Just looking at the basic structure here, it seems clear you have a `Father` and `Mother` and `Child` and `Partner` who are all `is a Person`. It appears all the other relationships are `has a` - ie. a Child (maybe) `has a Father`, etc. Don't let that arbitrary text file define your design. Create your object model first - then use the data from the file to fill in the holes. When it comes time to delete things it should seem quite natural how to accomplish that.